# Question About A Linear Algebra Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

A Car Rental service in a certain town has a fleet of about 500 cars, at three locations.  a car rented at one location may be returned to any of the three locations.  The various fractions of cars returned to the three locations are shown in the matrix.  Suppose that on Monday there are 195 cars at the airport (or rented from there), 55 cars at the east side office, and 250 cars at the west side office.  What will be the approximate distribution of cars.

On Wednesday BLANK cars will be at the airport, BLANK cars will be at the East location, and BLANK cars will be at the West location.

[image]

Can someone explain how to solve a problem like this?  Feel free to use different numbers so I can solve this exact question myself.

I took an approach that may be entirely wrong, but here is what I did.

Letting X_A represent Airport, X_E be East and X_W be West, and setting Equal to 0. I obtained the Matrix:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      .05&-.04&-.1&0\\
      0&.08&-.05&0\\
-.05&-.04&.15&0
    \end{array}
\right] $$
Row Reduced To:
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&0&-2.5&0\\
      0&1&-.625&0\\0&0&0&0\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

From this I determined that:

X_A=2.5X_W

X_E=.625X_W

X_W is Free

I don't think this really tells us anything and must have taken the entirely wrong approach.

Comment: Looks to me that this is just a plain matrix multiplication. The given matrix with a 3 by 1 vector containing the numbers 195, 55 and 295 In fact, since it covers two days, perform A² times the vector. Do you know why this works?

Comment: I understand the matrix multiplication part. I do not understand why you would do A^2 even with the information of it covering two days.

Comment: Because one multiplication gives you the distribution of the next day. Whatever those numbers are, you subject them again to the matrix. That in essence becomes a "double" multiplication of the matrix, hence the squared form. Similarly, if you want to know the distribution after 10 days, you would raise the matrix to power ten, and multiply that with the vector containing 195, 55, 250

Answer (score 2):

[Consider a Petri Net description of the car rental process](http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/1447152940.pdf). It is one way to organize the computation. It may also help you understand why the matrix of return rates is multiplied by itself twice.

The following image comes from [the interactive, dynamic PDF version](http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/1447152940.pdf) of this reply:

[image]